# "mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem" - what does this mean exactly?

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, ext3

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1, and my main partition is formatted as ext3. Checking `syslog` I see : `mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem` does this mean that the partition is mounted as `ext4`?

GParted and `blkid` show `ext3`.

Answer (score 10):

No, the partition is mounted as ext3; it's just that ext3 file systems [are handled by the ext4 driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext3.html) nowadays, with [the message you see when they're mounted](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.7/source/fs/ext4/super.c#L4055). There used to be a separate ext3 driver, but [it was dropped](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c290ea01abb7907fde602f3ba55905ef10a37477) when the ext4 driver had proven itself reliable. The ext4 driver checks that file systems mounted as ext3 only use ext3 features, so that they remain compatible with the old ext3 driver.